# Array sort with two requirements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have solved my trouble with sorting an array which is supposed to be sorted by the next two requirements:

1. Attributes with required on `true` are supposed be listed first.
2. Then alphabetically

I have done this, and it works but I have a feeling there is a clever way... :-|

```js
const originalAttributes = [{
    name: "P",
    required: false
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    required: true
  },
  {
    name: "W",
    required: true
  },
  {
    name: "A",
    required: true
  },
  {
    name: "N",
    required: false
  },
  {
    name: "S",
    required: false
  }
];

function listNames(originalAttributes) {
  originalAttributes.forEach(item => {
    console.log(`${item.name} ${item.required ? '--R' : ''}`);
  })
}

listNames(originalAttributes)

console.log('------------------------------');

const sortedAttributes = originalAttributes.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.required && b.required) {
    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
  } else if (a.required) {
    return -1
  } else if (!b.required) {
    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
  }
});

listNames(sortedAttributes)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be working, **P** is listed first but it is not required.

Comment: Noo under that you have correct list ;) First is `originalAttrinutes` and then `sortedAttributes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach like on the next example.

**Explanation:** the `unary plus` is used to cast the boolean to numbers, if the result of the difference of those booleans is `zero`, then use the comparison by `name` field with [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
const originalAttributes = [
    {name: "P", required: false},
    {name: "D", required: true},
    {name: "W", required: true},
    {name: "A", required: true},
    {name: "N", required: false},
    {name: "S", required: false},
    {name: "SI", required: false}
];

let res = originalAttributes.sort((a, b) =>
    (+b.required - +a.required) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
);

const listNames = a => a.map(
    i => `${i.name} ${i.required ? '--R' : ''}`
).join("\n");

console.log(listNames(res));
```